# One dimension deconvolutions or fully connected layers?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I’ve created a variational autoencoder to encode 1-dimensional arrays. The encoding is done through 3 1d-convolutional layers. Then, after the sampling trick, I reconstruct the series using 3 fully connected layers. Here are my questions in case some can shed some light on it:

I think it would be better if I use 1d-deconvolutional layers instead of fully connected, but I cannot understand precisely why.

- It’s because it would bring better results? But then, if the FC layer is complex enough should be able to archive the same results, right?
- It’s because would be more efficient? This is, would get the same results as a complex enough FC layer but with less training and parameters?
- Or it’s because of other reasons that I’m missing.

Thanks.